# partially specialize function template with no parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization

I think it's not possible but someone must know better...

```
template<typename T>   
T Read()   //T is int, char, etc
{
    return read<T>();
}

template<typename T, Size> 
std::array<T,Size> Read<std::array<T, Size>>()
{
     return unique_read<T, Size>();
}
```

I guess as soon as I specify any template argument it's no longer a full specialization, and partial specialization is not allowed in functions

The only thing I could come up with is:

```
template<typename T>
struct _dummy
{
    T Read() {
        return T();
    };
};

template<typename T, size_t Size>
struct _dummy<std::array<T, Size>>
{
    using ArrayType = std::array<T, Size>;

    ArrayType Read() {
        return ArrayType();
    };
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Right now you're just showing complicated ways of writing `T{}`.

Comment: @Barry I want to process all T's one way, except std:.arrays. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You probably want to make your `Read` static inside the `_dummy`, but other than that, this is a trick for partial function specialization.

Comment: @SergeyA The read function is in a class, so I guess I'd have to modify read to take a pointer to the outer class every time it's called and make it static, or create a _dummy object in my class and pass the pointer to the outer class only once. I wanted to avoid both things :<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use tag dispatching for this sort of job:

```
namespace detail {
template<class T>struct tag{};

template<class T>
T Read(tag<T>) {
    return T{};
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
std::array<T, N> Read(tag<std::array<T, N>>) {
    return {1,2,3};
}
}

template<class T>
auto Read() {
    return detail::Read(detail::tag<T>());
}

int main() {
    Read<std::array<int,5>>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll go for that one. I'm guessing since the argument is unnamed, the compiler should be smart enough to inline everything, and not pass any argument.

Comment: @Phantom Not because it's *unnamed*, no. Because it has trivial special member functions with no side effects.

Comment: @Phantom, and if you do not want to be at the mercy of the optimizer, you can always replace function argument with template argument and not create any object at all.

Comment: @SergeyA: but then, we are at the same state than start: we cannot partial specialize template function.

Comment: @Jarod42, don't know what I was thinking. You are right, of course.

Comment: @Barry Thanks for that, for some reason I thought only constructors / destructors could be trivial (silly me).

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do this is to defer to a function object:

```
template<class T> 
struct reader_op {
  T operator()() const { 
    // whatever needs to happen here
  }
};

// partially specialise for array case
template<class T, size_t N> 
struct reader_op<std::array<T, N>> {
  std::array<T, N> operator()() const { 
    // whatever needs to happen here
  }
};

// reader_op class type is now deduced from T
// when T is a std::array, our specialised function object will
// be used
template<typename T>   
T Read()   //T is int, char, etc
{
    return reader_op<T>()();
}
```